# How to manage multiple sessions in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, web-applications

I am developing a web app with ASP .net mvc, where i used sessions to store user's information.

But I faced a very weired behaviour, when I log in with a profil A and then in separate browser with profil B, I noticed that the profil A is replaced by B.  I don't know if this is a common issue, but I am thinking about creating an new table in database to store sessions.

```
protected void ASPxBtnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int codeRetour = IsUserOK(ASPxTxtBxLogin.Text, ASPxTxtBoxPssW.Text, null);

            if (codeRetour == CODE_LDAP_AUTH || codeRetour == CODE_INTERNE_AUTH)
            {
//OK
                Session["UserConnected"] = ASPxTxtBxLogin.Text;
                Session.Remove("LogOutAction");
                List<string> myLst = InfoUser(ASPxTxtBxLogin.Text, null);
                Session["UserCode"] = myLst[0];
                Helpers.UserID = Session["UserCode"].ToString(); 
                Session["UserCulture"] = myLst[1];
                Session["ApplicationStart"] = true;

                InitNbLigneModule();

                Response.Redirect(@"~\Ibiprod.aspx");
            }
            this.ASPxlblErreur.Text = Helpers.LibelleCodeRetour(codeRetour);

        }
```

I want to know how I can make in a way that multipul users with different roles can connect at the same to the server and not having this issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it an entirely different browser - like Edge and Chrome - or just another window in the same browser?

Comment: Entirely different, I used firefox and google for instance

Comment: Helpers.UserID - looks like its important & also looks like a static property? - if so  remember a single static property is shared across all requests.